# Find element (with variable xpath) in a HTML Code using Python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to automate my login process to a website that sends a verification code by email every time I try to log in. For this I'm using Python and Selenium.

Logging in to the website and clicking on the email containing the verification code in my gmail is fine but once I'm in the email I struggle to get the identification code.

I tried to use the xpath but the issue is the xpath is always different from a verification code to another.

For instance this is the xpath for one of the verification codes I received by email :

```py
//[@id=":qs"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div
```

And another one from a second verification code:

```py
//[@id=":3zm"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div
```

As you can see the id is different from one code to another, that's actually the only difference.

So I'm wondering whether I could get the verification code using another element from the HTML.

This is the HTML Code:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse" class="m_3010061996208616876email-body">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td height="50" class="m_3010061996208616876resize, m_3010061996208616876tdDefault"></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="m_3010061996208616876subHeader">
                                    Hello,
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="21" class="m_3010061996208616876tdDefault"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="m_3010061996208616876emailText"><span class="im">
                                    Your verification code is displayed below. Please use it in the next 15 minutes – after that time it'll expire.
                                    <br><br>

                                    </span><div style="text-align:center;font-size:42px;font-family:PublicoMedium,serif;color:#3e4e61;margin:0 auto;padding:0;line-height:42px">
                                        941976
                                    </div><span class="im">


                                    <br><br>
                                    If you run out of time and need to request a new one, you can do that on the website by clicking 're-send code'.
                                </span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="50" class="m_3010061996208616876tdDefault"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
```

In this one the verification code I'm looking to retrieve is 941976.

I've tried:

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(., 'text-align:center;font-size:42px;font-family:PublicoMedium,serif;color:#3e4e61;margin:0 auto;padding:0;line-height:42px')][1]")
```

but it does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Rémi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selector below:

```
td[class*='emailText'] div
```

Code:

```
verification_code = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td[class*='emailText'] div").text.strip()
```